# Disabling SIGABRT for a program run (Valgrind)

Tags: linux, valgrind

I have the task to debug a program using Valgrind. The program becomes very slow due to the Valgrind usage. This is a problem, because the program has a watcher thread that kills slow threads with SIGABRT if they spend too much time in certain functions. The program is in a valid state when it exits in that way, so I would like to keep it running even if SIGABRT is cast. I cannot change the program to switch off the watcher thread from the source code.

Now my question:

Does Valgrind, or a tool compatible with Valgrind, give me the option to say to the program: "If you receive SIGABRT, treat it as a null op and go on?"

Answer (score 1):

You might achieve what you want by running your program under valgrind + gdb, using vgdb.

With gdb, you can then control what to do with the SIGABRT signal.

For example, launch your program with:
valgrind --vgdb-stop-at=startup your_program

In another window, launch gdb:
   (gdb) handle SIGABRT nostop print nopass
   (gdb) target remote | vgdb
   (gdb) continue

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver for more information.

Comment: Will the nopass be enough to stop the program from terminating?

Comment: It should ... The best is to try with your application